# Solidity: How to inherit a struct to create a new struct?

Tags: solidity, struct, inheritance

Is there a way to inherit a previously defined struct while defining a new struct (similar to the classes in C++)?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
struct Person {
    bytes32 name;
    uint256 age;
}

struct Doctor : Person {
   bytes32 specialty;
   uint256 years_experience;
}
```

which would define Doctor to also have name and age.

Comment: struct Doctor { Person person; bytes32 specialty….}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works a little bit differently in solidity, you need to use a struct inside a struct. Example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract Example {

  struct Person {
      bytes32 name;
      uint256 age;
  }

  struct Doctor {
     Person person;
     bytes32 specialty;
     uint256 years_experience;
  }

  mapping (address => Doctor) mapAddrToDoc;

  function addDoctor(bytes32 name, uint256 age, bytes32 specialty, uint256 years_experience) public {
      Doctor memory doc = Doctor(Person(name, age), specialty, years_experience);
      mapAddrToDoc[msg.sender] = doc;
  }

  function getNameOfDoc(address addr) public view returns (bytes32){
      return mapAddrToDoc[addr].person.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to cover it. Usage-wise this seems a bit cumbersome compared to C++. From a memory perspective, do you think this approach is more efficient than simply defining separate structs without inheritance (Doctor having name/age/specialty/years_experience all separate)?

Comment: Try both and check which one is gas cheaper